# Is it possible to have multiple installation of framework7 on the same box?

Tags: javascript, linux, cordova, npm, html-framework-7

I'm working on a project with cordova 6.2.0 and framework7 1.6.5.
Now I've to start a new project based on cordova 7.1.0 and framework7 2.0.7.

I know that with version-manager-cordova-software [1] it's possible to run different cordova versions in the same development box, does exist something similar for framework7?

I'm searching for a working setup for both linux and osx.

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/version-manager-cordova-software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself: framework7 is always contained inside the cordova project, so it is possible to have different version on the same box.

The globally installed package is framework7-cli (https://www.npmjs.com/package/framework7-cli), actually at version 0.2.0, and it seems to work with both f7 v.1 and v.2.